# Асинхронная операция была отменена

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp, asp.net-core-mvc

Пытаюсь отправить письмо на электронную почту (код взят из документации [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netcore-2.0)), но операция отменяется и сообщение на почту не приходит. Помогите решить проблему.

```
static bool mailSent = false;
    private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        String token = (string)e.UserState;

        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] Send canceled.", token);
        }
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[{0}] {1}", token, e.Error.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
        }
        mailSent = true;
    }


    public static void SendMessage()
    {           
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.Port = 465;
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mailFrom, password);

        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(mailFrom,"saturn",System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(mailTo);

        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Body = "This is a test e-mail message sent by an application. ";

        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = "test message 1";
        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        client.SendCompleted += new
        SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);

        string userState = "test message1";
        client.SendAsync(message, userState);            

        if (mailSent == false)
        {
            client.SendAsyncCancel();
        }

        message.Dispose();
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вы пока только начинаете программировать на C#, лучше тогда пока писать обычный синхронный код и с асинхронностью не связываться.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин Язык я начал изучать летом 2016, просто сейчас решил научиться Web, а тут в примерах Microsoft и Metanit асинхронные методы..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы, конечно, взяли код у Microsoft-а, но выкинули ключевую строчку между `client.SendAsync` и проверкой:

string answer = Console.ReadLine();

И, соответственно, упростили проверку. Но код-то, вызвав `client.SendAsync`, ничего не ждет, а продолжает идти дальше и попадает в Ваш `if`, так как к этому моменту обработчик `SendCompletedCallback` еще не выполнился.

```
await client.SendMailAsync(message);
```

Comment: там функция без async объявлена

Comment: Спасибо. Надо бы почитать про асинхронность, а то пока даже не знаю, зачем это и когда используется)

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать синхронный вызов

```
client.Send(message, userState);
```

Или сделать асинхронно

```
await client.SendAsync(message, userState);
```

При этом незабываем добавить `async` в определение функции

```
public static async void SendMessage()
```